# what is an elegant way to implement this html table using css display:table + sass?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, mustache

What is an elegant way to define this html table using css display:table + sass?  I've defined a table layout using divs with display:table css styles:

```
    <div style="display:table">
        {{#definitions}}
        <div style="display:table-row">
            <div style="display:table-cell">{{key}}</div>
            <div style="display:table-cell">{{value}}</div>
        </div>
        {{/definitions}}
    </div>
```

The above example is a mustache template used for databinding. I need to move the style refs to sass.  What would be an elegant way to do this?

Comment: if you downvote then please include a comment describing why

Comment: Why don't you just use a normal `<table>`? You can use `<table>`'s to display data, but don't use them for layouts. I did not downvote.

Comment: Why can't you just assign a class to the the elements like you would any other? What does this have to do with SASS?

Comment: I need to keep the style refs separate from the html. Sass provides some additional capabilities to structure css in a more elegant way. I'm wondering if sass provides a good shortcut over vanilla css for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Yes SASS can help you structure your CSS in a more elegant way. What have you tried or are having problems with?

Comment: I think you need to show us your attempts because this should be incredibly simple in CSS or SASS. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: let's say I created a new class named 'divTable' and set class='divTable' for the outermost div in my example above. I could define this class in css as .divTable{display:table}. all 2nd-level divs could be inferred as display:table-row and all 3rd-level divs could be inferred as display:table-cell. this logic inference seems possible but I don't know if css or sass supports this or supports this in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are asking but you could do this with a single class on the outer element then target the child elements with `>` at each level to give you your rows and cells:

```
.display-table {
  display: table;

  >div {
    display: table-row;

    >div {
      display: table-cell;
    }
  }
}
```

which would generate the following CSS...

```css
.display-table {
  display: table;
}
.display-table > div {
  display: table-row;
}
.display-table > div > div {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="display-table">
  <div>
    <div>{{key}}</div>
    <div>{{value}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes this is correct or you could just use a `<table>` and not have to write any of this lol. Also would be better for screen readers and web crawlers I think

Comment: @zgood Perhaps OP is harnessing the presentation abilities of `display: table` rather than displaying tabular data. In which case a `<table>` should definitely _not_ be used.

Comment: He is displaying `{{key}}` `{{value}}` pairs, which is data

Comment: here is my scenario: a user will click on a help button next to a "report type" selector.  this will in turn open a popup which displays key/values of help info for the "report type" options.  I suppose this is tabular information. should I implement this in an actual table as opposed to a css table?